# Capture between brackets AND split by character

Tags: c#, regex

I've this regex: `{([^}]+)}`

It successfully captures bracket contents, e.g.
`hello {foo} and {bar}`.

I also want to capture groups inside that match separated by a character, e.g.
`hello {foo:bar} and {hello:world}`.

The former would produce a match on `{foo:bar}` with groups `{foo}` and `{bar}` and the latter `{hello:world}` with groups `{hello}` and `{world}`.

I'm not fluent in regex, and I've tried this: `{([^}]+)(:([^}]))?}` and `{([^}]+)(\:([^}]))?}` in case the : is a special character.

Which modification do I need to make to succeed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match both types of strings, you may use

```
{([^{}:]+)(?::([^{}]+))?}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6HxPqc/1)

**Details**

- `{` - a `{` char
- `([^{}:]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `{`, `}` and `:`
- `(?::([^{}]+))?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `:` - a colon
  - `([^{}]+)` - Group 2: 1+ chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for adding description also.

Comment: @Vincent You are welcome. I usually omit the description of auxiliary things, but you may read more about [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471) (`(?:...)`) and [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) (`[^...]`) if you wish.